# Howto set a root password in Freenas?

Tags: passwords, root, freenas, webgui

I installed Freenas 8.3.1 on my micro-server and it never asked me to set a root password. I already configured it as necessary via the web GUI but now i want to set a root password so no-one can mess with my configuration using the command line interface on the server itself,not on the web GUI. I already changed my default password for my admin account in the web GUI and I made sure that the "change root password as well" check-box is ticked but it still does not ask me for a root password after booting.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to your server as root using ssh (or on console) and type passwd you'll be asked for a new password.

Comment: okay great, i managed to set a password now but it still does not ask me to enter it after booting, it just boots up to the console menu without asking me for a password

Comment: Uncheck the setting "Enable console menu" in webgui at system>settings>advanced This will replace the console menu with a standard linux login screen.

Comment: Thanx i did so and then got the password prompt but i still want the console menu so i did a little further research and found a way to disable the console to get the password prompt and then re-enable the console after i enter the password.

Thanx for the help